# How to retrieve server control's values place inside user control after post back

Tags: asp.net

I have user control placed in my .aspx page. User controls are added dynamically on button click event. My problem is, after post back, I can retrieve server controls placed inside user control but cant retrieve their values.

Here is the code of my user control's .ascx page

```
   <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"   odeFile="qualificationControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="qualificationControl" %>
                    <table width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="RowHeight" width="20%">
                                Course Name</td>
                            <td width="20%">
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="courseList" runat="server" Width="100px">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                            <td width="20%">
                                Year of Passing</td>
                            <td width="*">
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="yearList" runat="server" Width="100px">
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="0">2005</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">2006</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="2">2007</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="3">2008</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="4">2009</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="RowHeight" width="20%">
                                Percentage</td>
                            <td colspan="3">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="percentageBox" runat="server">   </asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="RowHeight" width="20%">
                                Instutitute Name</td>
                            <td colspan="3">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="InstiNameBox" runat="server" Width="350px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
```

Here is the code of my .axcs.cs page

```
    using System;
     using System.Collections.Generic;
     using System.Linq;
     using System.Web;
     using System.Web.UI;
     using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
     using System.Data;

    public partial class qualificationControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            using (DataOperation oDo = new DataOperation())
            {
                DataTable dt = oDo.DropDownList("select * from tblqualificationMaster");
                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    courseList.Items.Add(new ListItem(row[1].ToString(), row[0].ToString()));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Code of my .aspx page

```
<%@ Page Title="Application Form Level2" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/AppMaster.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="AppplicationForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="AppplicationForm2" %>

<%@ Register src="Control/qualificationControl.ascx" tagname="qualificationControl" tagprefix="uc1" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="SubTitle">
            Education details:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td runat="server" id="tdQualificationn">

            <%--<uc1:qualificationControl ID="qualificationControl1" runat="server" />--%>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                   <asp:PlaceHolder ID="UserCtrlHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                </ContentTemplate>

           <%-- <Triggers> <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="addQualificationBtn" /></Triggers>--%></asp:UpdatePanel>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <asp:Button ID="addQualificationBtn" runat="server" 
                Text="Add More Qualifications" Height="40px" 
                onclick="addQualificationBtn_Click" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

</asp:Content>
```

Code of my .aspx.cs page

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.Collections;

    public partial class AppplicationForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        Control qualificationControl;
        UserControl usrqualificationControl = new UserControl();
    int CtrlID = 0;
    ArrayList CtrlList = new ArrayList();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        qualificationControl = usrqualificationControl.LoadControl("~/control/qualificationControl.ascx");
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ArrayList CtrlList = new ArrayList();
            qualificationControl.ID = CtrlID.ToString();
            UserCtrlHolder.Controls.Add(qualificationControl);
            CtrlList.Add(qualificationControl);
            Session.Add("qualiControl", CtrlList);
            Session.Add("ControlHolder", UserCtrlHolder);
        }
    }
    protected void addQualificationBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RememeberOldValues();
        if (Session["QualiControl"] != null)
        {
            CtrlList = (ArrayList)Session["qualicontrol"];
        }
        qualificationControl.ID = CtrlList.Count.ToString();
        CtrlList.Add(qualificationControl);
        for (int i = 0; i < CtrlList.Count; i++)
        {
            UserCtrlHolder.Controls.Add((Control)CtrlList[i]);
        }
    }    
    public void RememeberOldValues()
    {
        try
        {
            if (Session["ControlHolder"] != null)
                {
                    ArrayList CourseList = new ArrayList();
                    ArrayList YearList = new ArrayList();
                    ArrayList percentageList = new ArrayList();
                    ArrayList InstituteList = new ArrayList();
                    ArrayList CtrlList = (ArrayList)Session["qualicontrol"];
                    PlaceHolder PlaceHolder = (PlaceHolder)Session["ControlHolder"];
                    for (int intListCnt = 0; intListCnt < CtrlList.Count; intListCnt++)
                    {
                        Control userControl = (Control)PlaceHolder.FindControl(CtrlID.ToString());
                        DropDownList dlCourseList = (DropDownList)userControl.FindControl("courseList");
                        DropDownList dlYearList = (DropDownList)userControl.FindControl("yearList");
                        TextBox percentageBox = (TextBox)userControl.FindControl("percentageBox");
                        TextBox InstiNameBox = (TextBox)userControl.FindControl("InstiNameBox");

                        CourseList.Add(dlCourseList.SelectedValue);
                        YearList.Add(dlYearList.SelectedValue);
                        percentageList.Add(percentageBox.Text);
                        InstituteList.Add(InstiNameBox.Text);
                    }
                }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Please guide me how can I retrieve those values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to find particular control from user control

```
((DropDownList)qualificationControl1.FindControl("yearList")).SelectedValue
```

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar....I have done so. By doing like this,controls are found but its values are not retrieved.

Comment: put this in Page_Init event and then try     qualificationControl = usrqualificationControl.LoadControl("~/control/qualificationControl.ascx");

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar..Which part you want me to put in page_Init() method?

Comment: qualificationControl = usrqualificationControl.LoadControl("~/control/qualificationControl.ascx");

Comment: why not visible/invisble the user control in code behind instead loading at runtime ?

Comment: @Muhammand Akhatar..I have tried using Page_Init(),Still its not working. I am only getting dropdown list's default values. Cant understand your second option. What is the mistake in my approach??

Comment: I mean why you are loading user control in your code. you can just put it aspx page and visible/invisible upon any condition

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar...I have to do so because number of controls are not fixed, it varies from user to user.This is part of application form for recruitment portal. So number of qualification varies from user to user. Moreover, Below this, there will be another user control for the experience part which is yet to develop.So by making it visible/invisible will not server my purpose.

Comment: can you try to put this under if(!IsPostBack) { qualificationControl = usrqualificationControl.LoadControl("~/control/qualificationControl.ascx"); }

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar..I did it using(!isPostBack) still its not working. During debug, if I check datavalue field and data text field of dropdown lists, it shows empty, but they are giving me default values.